# Create 10 different files from a list of 10 elements in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a question that maybe could be really simple to solve but I cannot find a way to do this.

I have a list of 10 elements that I want to convert in 10 different `data.frames` of 88 observation with 2 variables (to put them in a loop with for or replicate and iterate the same process for all the 10 different files). When I convert it using the `as.data.frame` function, I obtain a single `data.frame` of 88 observation with 20 variables, i.e. the 10 different `data.frames` got combined together.

Do you know how can I solve this issue? Thank you so much

Comment: Would a command like `lapply(list_of_10, as.data.frame)` solve your problem?

Comment: I just tried the command as you wrote it, and actually it returns the same `list` as before.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, I think the R18's answer does what you want

Comment: @Lore_Bernicchi reading between the lines, you seem to want to combine your data horizontally; i.e. make it wider by column binding  ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have the following list of `data.frame`:

```
# Build the list
  aux <- list()

# Define its 10 elements
  for (i in 1:10){
    aux[[i]] <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), Y = runif(10))
  }
```

We are going to name each element (`data.frame`) as A1, A2, . . .

```
for (i in 1:10){
  nam <- paste("A", i, sep = "")
  assign(nam, aux[[i]])
}
```

Now, apart from the list, you have 10 different elements (A1, A2, . . ., A10) containing the information you have inside it.

Comment: Thank you so much R18, that was really useful! Anyway, in this way it creates ten 10 different elements with 10 different names. After that, I would like to insert those elements in a `for` loop and perform, on all of them, the same process. May I ask you if there is a way to do that? Maybe I wasn't clear enough with the first question, I am sorry

Comment: Hi @Lore_Bernicchi! To do the same thing to all the elements in a list you can use `lapply` function. For example, to know the dimension of each table `lapply(aux,dim)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(my_list_of_3_thing <- lapply(1:3,
                               \(x)data.frame(lval= rep(letters[x],4),
                                              fnum = rep(x,4))))

(gathered_df <- do.call("cbind",my_list_of_3_thing))

# name them better?
names(gathered_df) <- make.unique(names(gathered_df))
gathered_df
```